# How to skip a particular scenario on Jbehave tests?

Tags: java, skip, jbehave

I have a particular scenario which is not ready for testing yet. So I need to skip it in order to run the tests on other scenarios.

```
Scenario: Login-success Scenario:

Meta:
@skip
@ignored true

//Regular Steps
```

Comment: Why would you need to skip it? Just let it go red until you fix it. Why would it interfere with your other tests? Can you please elaborate or show us an example?

Comment: yes it does.. some steps repeat right? Example : User Enters Username and Password. I cannot have different implementations for each scenario.

Comment: It wont pass if its red. By pass i mean. it wont go to the next scenario

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `@skip` or `@ignore true` meta in a story to skip this story,
you need to configure a meta filter in configuration of your test.

Depending on how you configure your test, it could be for example:

```
@RunWith(AnnotatedEmbedderRunner.class)
@UsingEmbedder(metaFilters = {"-skip"})
public class AnnotatedTraderEmbedder extends InjectableEmbedder {
}
```

or, in Java:

```
public MyStories() {
    configuredEmbedder().embedderControls().doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
        .doIgnoreFailureInStories(true)
        .doIgnoreFailureInView(true).useThreads(1); 
    // Meta filters:
    configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));
}
```

See the documentation for details: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html

Comment: Looks cool, although still not obvious how to set the embedder globally and where to put the cod and how to configure JBehave to see this Embedder.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply skip the test using the @skip in the meta info:

```
Scenario:  A scenario which we cannot run every time due to some technical contraint
Meta:
@skip     
@ignored true  
Given ... // normal scenario steps
```

Documentation on meta tags can be found [here](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-info.html)

Comment: This some how doesnt work. I have seen the documentation. The scenario still runs.

Comment: @AkaashVankamamidi Could you please edit your question to provide some examples of what you have tried?